# Including a forward slash within org mode italics block

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org mode (Emacs-24.4.1) I am trying to include a forward slash in a sentence that is italic but it is used as the italic boundary e.g.

```
/Using double Flk1^{-/-} mutants/
```

where I want the whole sentence italicised and the forward slash to be included in the superscript. I realise I can put a space between the first "-" and the "/" but this looks ugly. Also I could put it into a latex block but I was looking for something where it is italicised in the buffer as well. Is there some way of escaping it?

Comment: You might try playing with `org-emphasis-regexp-components`, but simplest is to write `- / -` which is not that ugly.

Comment: You should've asked this on Emacs.SE (or optionally on org-mode's more active mailing list).

Answer (score 3):

You might try this:

```
/Using double Flk1\slash{} mutants/
```

The `{}` are not actually needed in this case, but if after `\slash{}` wouldn't be a whitespace.

Although I must say, that this method in other cases is all but handy – f.e. when writing paths. Unfortunately org-mode has no consistent escaping concept until now.

(Also yet I didn't found the same for backslash – `\backslash{}` does not work for unknown reasons.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to write `- \ -`, you can use verbatim environnement:

`/Using double Flk1 =-/=- mutants/`.

if you use `=-/-=`, mutants will not be emphased in the buffer but `=-/=-` do the trick.